# Is there a root system for a Dihedral group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, coxeter-groups

Let $G$ be a Coxeter group of type $I_m$ ($m \geq 3$). Then $G$ is a Dihedral group. When $m=3,4,6$, $G$ is of type $A_2, B_2, G_2$ respectively. There are root systems for $A_2, B_2, G_2$. Is there a root system for $I_m$ (for example $m=5$)? If there is one, then we will have two simple roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$. What is the ratio $||\alpha_1||/||\alpha_2||$ of the lengths of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$? Thank you very much.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429688/lie-algebra-like-structure-corresponding-to-noncrystallographic-root-systems/1429701#1429701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a root system of type $I_m$ only exists for the cases $m = 3,4,6$ you mentioned.

In fact, the irreducible root systems can be classified via Dynkin diagrams and the only possibilities there are $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, $D_n$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$, $F_4$ and $G_2$.

Comment: thank you very much. I found one definition of root systems for any Coxeter group in [the paper](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/PG/Theses/X-Fu-2010_thesis.pdf), Definition 1.2.2. The definition of the action of Coxeter group on the root system is defined in the second paragraph on page 13: $r_s x = x − 2<x, \beta_s> \alpha_s$. I don't know how to compute the action explicitly in the case of dihedral group $I_m$.

Comment: Yes, this definition is a generalization of the usual definition of root system. If you are interested in this situation, I suggest, you edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, there **are** root systems for **all** dihedral groups, there simply aren't any **crystallographic** root systems for dihedral groups with $m\neq 2,3,4,6$. So it depends what definition of root system you're using. For instance neither Kane (Reflection groups and Invariant theory) nor Humphrey (Reflection groups and Coxeter groups) impose the crystallographic condition ($\frac{2(\alpha,\beta)}{(\beta,\beta)}\in \mathbb{Z}$) on root systems.

Comment: In Humprey it depends which chapter you're reading - in first chapter there is no crystallographic condition assumed